# Repeat test including beforeClass with Junit

Tags: junit

We are setup our test environment in beforeClass static method and sometimes it fails and we would like to detect it and repeat setup of test environment. Does it possible to do this thing with junit?

Comment: Why is your code in the @BeforeClass section failing? Can you give more information about what exactly your set up is attemping to do/what your goals are?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the setup in the test or in `@Before` instead of `@BeforeClass`. The point of `@BeforeClass` is to do stuff you only need to do once.